# Search in the multiply tree view doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

have a problem with the implamantation search in the multiple tree view.
Can check the code in the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-esd8zp?file=src%2FApp.js).
In the group we have `childGroup` and `list`, we have to search lists and groups names. (check data in the data.js file)

Think the problem is somewhere here.

```
const search = (items, term) => {
    return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
      if (contains(item.name, term)) {
        acc.push(item);
      } else if (item.childGroupList?.length) {
        let newGroupsItems = search(item.childGroupList, term);
        if (newGroupsItems?.length) {
          item.childGroupList = newGroupsItems;
          acc.push(item);
        }
      } else if (item.list?.length) {
        let newListItems = search(item.list, term);
        if (newListItems?.length) {
          item.list = newListItems;
          acc.push(item);
        }
      }

      return acc;
    }, []);
  };
```

Comment: Which kind of scenarios seems to be not working? Can you please explain an example?

Comment: You can try to type "alfa" for example.  Should show SomeName => One => Alfa, AnotherName => sample_123 => Alfa, Alfa (root group). It shows only root Alfa and AnotherName => sample_123 => Alfa (not expanded will fix later). SomeName => One => Alfa not showing.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few issues in your recursive `search`.

1. Your `if`, `else if`, `else if` chain should be independent. They should really be three `if` blocks.
2. You need to push the result only after when all the searches are done at a certain level. I got a copy of the item and make `childGroupList` and `list` properties empty(`[]`) initially and update them when a search is successful.

Try like this.

```
  // main search function, here is the problem
  const search = (items, term) => {
    return items.reduce((acc, item) => {
      let itemCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
      itemCopy.childGroupList = [];
      itemCopy.list = [];
      let found = false;
      if (contains(item.name, term)) {
        found = true;
      }
      if (item.childGroupList?.length) {
        let newGroupsItems = search(item.childGroupList, term);
        if (newGroupsItems?.length) {
          found = true;
          itemCopy.childGroupList = newGroupsItems;
        }
      }
      if (item.list?.length) {
        let newListItems = search(item.list, term);
        if (newListItems?.length) {
          found = true;
          itemCopy.list = newListItems;
        }
      }
      if (found) {
        acc.push(itemCopy);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  };
```

Code sandbox => https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rmrlj1?file=src%2FApp.js

[image]

Comment: @Kostya Polishko, check this out !!

Comment: Thank you so much, seems to be working.  Sorry didn't have time to check on weekends.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera can we do same thing in angular also, can you help me to do it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-view-16feb

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar, it should be possible. But I'm not experienced in Angular TBH